# CodeIgniter CSRF Not Working on Subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I am using CodeIgniter to run my application which is split into two sections. A "user" section based at example.com and a "business" section based at business.example.com. When using the user section the CSRF token is automatically added into the form fields when I use the `form_open` function but does not on the business section.

Config.php

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.'.ltrim(rtrim($config['base_url'], '/'), 'http://'); //generates ".example.com"
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution I ventured into the system folder and changed some code in the `form_helper` file. Line 94 looks for the form `action` to be equal to the base url (http://example.com) and does not take into account for sub domains (http://business.example.com). Changed line 94 from:

```
if ($CI->config->item('csrf_protection') === TRUE && strpos($action, $CI->config->base_url()) !== FALSE && ! stripos($form, 'method="get"'))
```

to

```
if ($CI->config->item('csrf_protection') === TRUE && strpos($action, ltrim($CI->config->base_url(), 'http://')) !== FALSE && ! stripos($form, 'method="get"'))
```

basically I have trimmed the "http://" from the base url and I am looking for "example.com" instead of "http://example.com". I would love to still know a solution which does not involve modifying the core files.